# Scrapy why bother with Items when you can just directly insert?

Tags: python, scrapy

I will be using scrapy to crawl a domain. I plan to store all that information into my db with sqlalchemy. It's pretty simple xpath selectors per page, and I plan to use HttpCacheMiddleware.

In theory, I can just insert data into my db as soon as I have data from the spiders (this requires hxs to be instantiated at least). This will allow me to bypass instantiating any Item subclasses so there won't be any items to go through my pipelines.

I see the advantages of doing so as:

1. Less CPU intensive since there won't be any CPU processing for the pipelines
2. Prevents memory leaks.

Disk I/O is a lot faster than Network I/O so I don't think this will impact the spiders a lot.

Is there a reason why I would want to use Scrapy's Item class?

Answer (score 7):

If you insert directly inside a spider, then your spider will block until the data is inserted. If you create an Item and pass it to the Pipeline, the spider can continue to crawl while the data is inserted. Also, there might be race conditions if multiple spiders try to insert data at the same time.

Comment: Race conditions will be taken care by Sqlalchemy's thread pool. Disk IO is much slower than Network IO so that shouldn't present a significant risk

Comment: Depending on you use case, the time it take to store data can be significant. For example, you have to process data before storing, or the storage is on a different machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I feel the upvoted answer isn't really correct.

> Is there a reason why I would want to use Scrapy's `Item` class?

The Scrapy model of web scraping is essentially:

1. Collecting data with spiders.
2. Bundling that data into items.
3. Processing those items with item pipelines.
4. Storing those items somewhere with yet another item pipeline.

Steps 3 and 4 comprise the "big" item pipeline. If you don't subclass `Item`, you cannot enter an object into the item pipeline, so you're forced to normalize the fields and insert the item into your database all within your spider.

If you *do* subclass `Item`, you can make your item processing code much more maintainable:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import MapCompose, Identity

class Product(Item):
    name = Field()
    price = Field()

    aisle = Field()
    categories = Field()

class ProductLoader(XPathItemLoader):
    default_item_class = Product

    price_in = MapCompose(parse_price)
    categories_out = Identity()
```

Comment: "If you don't subclass Item, you cannot enter an object into the item pipeline, so you're forced to normalize the fields and insert the item into your database all within your spider." This is not true. You can use a basic Python dictionary instead of Scrapy ```Item``` class, pass your scraped object to the pipeline and process it there. And I am still wondering why we need the Item class indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have multiple spiders in the same project having an Item makes it easier to mange it if you want/need to change items. Say you wan to add item and having declared Item you can do all in one place. Otherwise you will need to do so in each and every spider you have in the project.  But for smaller projects its not the case obviously.